# Elasticsearch responding blank _source

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, koa

I am using `@elastic/elasticsearch` library in my node project and i am trying to create an index like this

```
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')
const client = new Client({ node: 'http://localhost:9200' })
await client.index({
    index: 'myIndex',
    refresh: true,
    body: {
        category: '',
        something_else: ''
    }
})
```

When i am trying to fetch a record

```
const { body } = await client.search({
    index: 'myIndex',
    body: {
        query: {
            "match_all": {}
        }
    }
})
```

The response is

```
 {
    "_index": "myIndex",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "cjijWHEBHKa8WEr-JNYu",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {}
},
```

Comment: provided answer, please have a look and let me know if have further questions

Comment: just for the example i had written a blank text..i am actually passing data there.

Comment: can you share your ES mapping then? hope you have not disabled it in your mapping {
  "mappings": {
    "_source": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  }
} like this?

Comment: {"myIndex":{"mappings":{}}}

Comment: I tried with this as well, may I know the version u using ?

Comment: elasticsearch 7.0.1

Comment: i guess my issue got resolved by removing the elasticsearch from wsl to normal windows. I was trying it out in Windows subsystem for linux with ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211335/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-vivek-jha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically missed a small thing, while indexing you are sending empty data in both your `category` and `something_else` field and in `_source` field, ES stores what you send as part of your JSON payload. `_id` is auto-generated in your case, hence you see the data there, but it was not part of your `body(JSON payload)`, which would form `_source` content, hence its empty.

If you just include some data in your fields, those documents will have the `_source` data.

**Let me show you by an example.**

### Index Def

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "category": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "something_else": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index doc with empty data.

POST /{{your-index-name}}/_doc/1

```
{
   --> note empty data or payload
}
```

### Search request

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

**Search response which shows empty `_source`**

```
   "hits": [
           {
            "_index": "justno",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {} --> Output similar to yours
        }
        ]
```

### Index doc with some sample data

```
{
    "category": "foo",
    "something_else": "bar"
}
```

### Again match-all search query, gives below result

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "justno",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": { --> doc which had data, while indexing
                    "category": "foo",
                    "something_else": "bar"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "justno",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {} --> note first doc response
            }
        ]
```

Comment: I'm adding index/_doc with this kind of sample data. 
{
    "company_name":"name check",
    "company_email": "test@yopmail.com",
    "merchant": 12,
    "price": 98
}
If I'm trying to search document data on kibana console for same index it's giving _source value but for the same document _source is empty while checking in postman.

Comment: @radhikathakkar, can you provide the complete URL of your request and response from postman

Comment: Postman API => http://localhost:3005/v1/elastic/search
{
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "index2",
                "_id": "Qj9Aq4EBm7k2dL95BZM6",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {}
            },
            {
                "_index": "index2",
                "_id": "Qz9Fq4EBm7k2dL95hJNp",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {}
            }
        ]
}

Comment: cloud url => https://{{cloudurl}}:9243/index2/_search?pretty=true
`
{
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "index2",
                "_id": "Qj9Aq4EBm7k2dL95BZM6",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "company_email": "test@yopmail.com",
                    "company_name": "name check",
                    "price": 98
                }
            }
]
} 
`

Comment: can you please check here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72790352/node-js-elasticsearch-responding-blank-source