# Node.Js Elasticsearch Responding Blank _source

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have created one sample index using elasticsearch and node.js with below code setup.

```
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch');
const { ELASTIC_SEARCH } = require('../config');

// Elastic Search Cloud Client Setup
const elasticClient = new Client({
    cloud: { id: ELASTIC_SEARCH.CLOUDID },
    auth: {
        apiKey: ELASTIC_SEARCH.API_KEY
    }
});


async function prepareIndex() {
const merchantIndexExists = await elasticClient.indices.exists({ index: 'index2' }); 
        if (merchantIndexExists) return;
        await elasticClient.indices.create({
            index: 'index2',
            body: {
                mappings: {
                    dynamic: 'strict',
                    properties: {
                        company_name: { type: 'text' },
                        company_email: { type: 'keyword' },
                        name: { type: 'text' },
                        price: { type: 'scaled_float', scaling_factor: 10 },
                        created_date: { type: 'date' },
                        is_delete: { type: 'boolean', doc_values: false },
                        merchant: { type: 'keyword', index: 'true' }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
  }
```

After index creation i have added document with below code:

```
const { company_name, company_email, price } = req.body;
        const response = await elasticClient.index({
            index: 'index2',
            document: {
                company_email,
                company_name,
                price
            }
        });
```

Now when I'm calling search API from my kibana cloud console it's returning the exact search results with all the fileds. like
[image]

But when I'm hitting same search query via code in postman it's returning blank _source. Here is the search query with postman response

```
const response = await elasticClient.search({
            index: 'index2',
            query: {
                match_all: {}
            }
        });
```

[image]

Can anyone please help me out of this?

Answer (score 0):

When using the Node.js ElasticSearch client, you have to wrap the query into a body property and pass it to the search.

```
const response = await elasticClient.search({
  index: 'index2',
  body: {
    query: {
      match_all: {}
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried with this also but it's giving same response
Any another solution?

Comment: It looks like there is something more that happens in your application. Can you show me your full source code?

Using the source code from your question, I'm getting the expected result.